# Join a table with duplicate entries for a label but not for the ID column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following table Fact_Sales :

```
ProductSK DateSK SalesAmount SalesNumber 
1         2019   300         150 
2         2019   500         190 
.....
```

and the following table DimProduct :

```
ProductSK CategoryLabel 
1         ABC 
2         ABC 
....
```

I want to calculate the  sales by category label but when joining like below the result of the query is generating a cartesian product :

```
SELECT CategoryLabel, SUM(SalesAmount)
FROM    Fact_Sales,     DimProduct
```

Comment: You are missing the GROUP clause in your query

Comment: Avoid implicit joins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Answer (score 1):

You should use `INNER JOIN ON` instead:

```
SELECT CategoryLabel, SUM(F.SalesAmount)
FROM Fact_Sales AS F INNER JOIN DimProduct AS D ON F.ProductSK = D.ProductSK
GROUP BY D.CategoryLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT join to the distinct values of your Product table :

```
SELECT DP.CategoryLabel, SUM(FS.SalesAmount)
FROM Fact_Sales AS FS
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT ProductSK,CategoryLabel FROM DimProduct
) AS DP
ON DP.ProductSK=FS.ProductSK
GROUP BY DP.CategoryLabel
```